# IDE for AR in android

Tags: android, image-processing, augmented-reality

Can you suggest the best IDE for creating a AR(augmented reality) application on android and why? like IntelliJ IDEA or eclipse?

Comment: I fail to see how IDE choice will impact augmented reality application development. Personally, I use IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I think on 
"eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32" you are able to develop all Android Application.